# A user spamming

Tags: support, status-completed, spam

Okay I ran out of flags https://superuser.com/users/31186/user31186 is spamming hardcore on Superuser

Comment: You can always flag a post for moderator attention even after you've ran out of spam/offensive flags (and close votes) for the day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for the heads up.  Issue has been taken care of.

Comment: No problem, he ruined my active view for awhile :( You don't screw with my active view!